# How to generate CA bundle for self signed SSL?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I have generated website certificate file using openssl command

`sudo openssl genrsa -out custom.key 4096`

`sudo openssl req -new -key custom.key -out my-wbsite.cert -x509 -days 365`

and installed in hosting panel all are correct showing in online ssl checker but browser showing error "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" its due to CA bundle missing but  am not found process to create CA bundle.

Thanks

Comment: A self-signed certificate, by definition, is not under any CA, and a DIY one like yours is not a CA itself; it must be verified manually and individually, and is sometimes treated as a 'pseudo-CA' for that purpose by some clients e.g. browsers. But this is not a programming or development issue.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085:- thanks for explaination so according to you I can't able to use self-signed certification in my website right?

Comment: It depends on your client(s) and usage. You can't have it trusted by chaining to a CA in the normal way, but you can trust it directly from many (most?) client(s), with the disadvantages that if multiple clients you must configure each separately and you must re-configure (all) if and when you replace/renew the cert, and you can bypass/disable trust in some client(s), with the disadvantage that you throw away much of your security. Your choice.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 but browser not accept certification without CA file I have already used certificate and key file actually I want to use SSL on a normal informative website there is noting like that there need to use paid ssl

Comment: All browsers I know of can be manually set to accept a self-signed certificate without an actual CA; if yours can't you're probably doing it wrong. But if you want browsers to accept a cert _without_ manual intervention, then you do need to use an _established_ CA; that doesn't necessarily mean paid.

Comment: thanks a lot @dave_thompson_085 for your knowledge can you share any link from where I can found the  established CA. I found a link but there CA file for different SSL provider like Comodo,GoDaddy SSL